# DOCTYPE RSS & HTML entities

Tags: html, rss, feed, entities

I have an **"ldquo"**, **"rdquo"** and several other entities under my RSS feed. Seems like if I add

```
<!DOCTYPE rss [
  <!ENTITY % HTMLspec PUBLIC
  "-//W3C//ENTITIES Latin 1 for XHTML//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-special.ent">
  %HTMLspec;
```

below the **xml** tag and above the **rss** tag then I'll be able to include those entities. I added but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone knows what I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

it doesn't seem likely that many feed readers will know what to do with that.  i would recommend sticking with numbered entity references.  for example, change `&ldquo;` to `&#8220;`.  you can get the full entity reference [right here from w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/entities.html).

additionally, you can read [this article](http://myst-technology.com/public/item/11878) and [this one](http://dotjay.co.uk/2006/sep/named-html-entities-in-rss) which gives some good tips on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Forget entities. Just use UTF-8 for all characters.

It will work reliably regardless whether RSS clients properly parse XML or not (sadly, the latter isn't uncommon).

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough but in RSS instead of

`&rsquo;`

I used

`&amp;rsquo;`

and it worked in all browsers that I have (IE, Mozilla, Google Chrome)